# Django view being called with no kwargs

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I have a `django.views.generic.DetailView`-based class called `LocationView` that is set up like this:

```
class LocationView(DetailView):
    model = Location
    pk_url_kwarg = 'location_id',
    template_name = 'accounts/locations/view_location.html'
```

And the corresponding url definition:

```
url(
    r'^accounts/(?P<account_id>\d+)/locations/(?P<location_id>\d+)/$'
    LocationView.as_view(),
    name='view_location',
)
```

When I try to access `LocationView` in my browser, I get the following exception:

> AttributeError: Generic detail view LocationView must be called with
>   either an object pk or a slug.

After much digging, I found out that somewhere along the line, `self.pk_url_kwarg` gets changed from `'location_id'` to `('location_id', )`, which causes the view to fail to retrieve the object's pk when it runs `self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)` because none of the keys in `self.kwargs` matches the modified `pk_url_kwarg` value.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

`django.VERSION == (1, 11, 'final', 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've set it to a tuple:

```
pk_url_kwarg = 'location_id',
```

Note the trailing comma. That is what turns a statement into a tuple. To fix it, simply remove the comma:

```
pk_url_kwarg = 'location_id'
```

Comment: Yup, that does it! Marking as answer as soon as it lets me. I'm one relieved idiot!